# Easiest/safest way to pass information cell by cell to a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I have a very long algorithm I've been working on, and I would like to leave it running for days. I'd like to save the results and other variables to a dataframe for each loop and later pass them to a csv or xlsx file. For example, in this loop:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

for attempt in range(3):
    if attempt==0:
        string_class = 'First Class'
    else:
        string_class = 'Other Class'
    executing_alg = True
    while executing_alg:
        time_tst = dt.now()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        result_1 = random.random()
        result_2 = random.random()
        if result_1 > result_2:
            executing_alg=False
```

I would like to save the variables `time_tst`, `result_1`, `result_2`, and `string_class`. As a result, I would like to have a dataframe filled with these variables from each loop execution. Expected result:

| Time | Result_1 | Result_2 | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-16 02:35:11.069372 | 0.6570918119177281 | 0.043825063850461254 | First Class |
| 2022-05-16 02:35:11.479732 | 0.26843513214552006 | 0.010366867417694214 | Other Class |
| 2022-05-16 02:35:11.682106 | 0.9087965555346139 | 0.7634101174048724 | Other Class |

What comes to my mind is to make a list with the results and then append them to the series in the dataframe... but I guess there are easier and faster ways?... Thanks for any suggestion...

Comment: Does it have to be pandas? I don't see you using pandas for anything else so using it simply to save results seems like a waste of energy.

Comment: No, could be writing direclty to csv, but I thought with pandas might be simpler

Comment: Creating a DataFrame and then writing later... on something you plan to run for days, has the potential to fill up your memory and/or spontaneously crash, losing everything you've loaded into memory but haven't saved yet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Using csv now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would write a new line in CSV format to a file for every loop. You can later read this easily with pandas, but there's no reason to use pandas to do this.

```
import random
import datetime as dt

with open('datafile.csv', 'a') as f:
    for attempt in range(3):
        if attempt==0:
            string_class = 'First Class'
        else:
            string_class = 'Other Class'
        executing_alg = True
        while executing_alg:
            time_tst = dt.now()
            time.sleep(0.2)
            result_1 = random.random()
            result_2 = random.random()
            if result_1 > result_2:
                executing_alg=False
        """
        It's not clear whether or not this next line
        should in inside your while loop or not.
        ...Adjust as needed:
        """
        f.write(f'{time_tst},{result_1},{result_2},{string_class}')
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very close to what I expect, however, I guess I need to add a "," at the end of the f'string to separate the next loop. Is there any way to setup the 2nd loop run on a 2nd row, 3rd loop in 3rd and so on?

Comment: Nevermind, just needed to add the \n Thanks!.

Comment: Fixed it with a good way of adding the newline I'd missed before~